# CSS Background image not showing IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following css code

```
#gel{position:absolute; width:20px; height:22px; margin-left:5px; color:#FF0000;background:url('../images/GEL-CURENCY.jpg') repeat-x;background-color:transparent;}
```

and this is my script

```
document.getElementById("small_txt_container_2").innerHTML = '<span id=\"gel\"></span>';
```

it does not working in IE 8, please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

if problem is only in IE8 then include this logic in the `<head>`

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` refers to what goes inside of your HTML tags, not the tags themselves. Look at this example, it will help you understand how to use pure JS to get a new `<span>` into your page.

```
(function(){   
    // 1- Establish new element
    var newItem = document.createElement('span');

    // 2- Add className
    newItem.className = 'gel';

    // 3- Put content into <span> tags
    newItem.innerHTML = 'stuff inside the brackets';

    // 4- Tell your program to put the span just after an item with your-ID-here
    document.getElementById('your-ID-here').appendChild(newItem);           
})();
```

Comment: I need to show image after text in html, so i have used html span element with css class. Css clas works well text color and so on, but background property doew not working

Comment: My main problem is that, i want to use gergian currency logo/icon after text. IE 8 does not shows my icon it look like '₾'.  I could not find aprobriate unicode character so i deside to use span element with image backgrount. but it does not working too

Comment: `textContent` allows you to put unicode characters into the JS-generated DIVs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent, but it's only IE9 and up. You'll probably need a polyfill - check that link it shows you how.